# Deploying CXF resource adaptor on JBoss 6.1

Tags: java, exception, deployment, jboss, cxf

I'm trying to deploy CXF JCA resource adapter on JBoss using IRONJACAMAR with following `ironjacamar.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:ironjacamar xmlns:p="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema ">
    <p:connection-definitions>
        <p:connection-definition jndi-name="java:/CXFConnector" class-name="org.apache.cxf.jca.outbound.CXFConnectionFactory">
            <p:pool>
                <p:min-pool-size>10</p:min-pool-size>
                <p:max-pool-size>100</p:max-pool-size>
            </p:pool>
            <p:security>
               <p:application/>
            </p:security>           
        </p:connection-definition>
    </p:connection-definitions>
</p:ironjacamar>
```

This XML file is located inside CXFResourceAdapter.rar/META-INF, which is inside our ear.

what I get is:

```
16:27:25,468 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ra.deployer."OURServer.ear#CXFResourceAdapter": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ra.deployer."OURServer.ear#CXFResourceAdapter": JBAS010446: Failed to start RA deployment [OURServer.ear#CXFResourceAdapter]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.start(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:116)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: org.apache.cxf.jca.cxf.AssociatedManagedConnectionFactoryImpl not a valid connection definition
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.findConnectionDefinitions(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:476)
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:1847)
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:1104)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService$AS7RaDeployer.doDeploy(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:197)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.start(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:112)
    ... 5 more
```

I'v foud there are two classes called `CXFConnectionFactory` located in packages `org.apache.cxf.jca.outbound` and `org.apache.cxf.connector`.

We used `org.apache.cxf.connector.CXFConnectionFactory` on JBoss 5 and it worked fine.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found a solution. The mistake was in the `class-name` attribute of connection definition part.

The correct class for that is `org.apache.cxf.jca.cxf.AssociatedManagedConnectionFactoryImpl`.